# Setting cursor position on textbox after postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am able to focus on the textbox after postback using this code:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(textBox, textBox.GetType(), "selectAndFocus", "$get('" + textBox.ClientID + "').focus();", true);
```

But this sets the cursor position to the beginning of the textbox, not after the last typed character. I try to solve this by using this code:

```
textBox.Attributes.Add("onfocus", "$get('" + textBox.ClientID + "').value = $get('" + textBox.ClientID + "').value;");
```

But that doesn't work. Same result as before.
How can I solve this?

I have read a ton of links, [this](http://parentnode.org/javascript/working-with-the-cursor-position/) seeming like the best solution, but I haven't been able to get it to work.

UPDATE: Forgot to mention that the textbox resides inside an updatepanel.

UPDATE2, attempted solution:

```
string setCaretTo = @"function setCaretTo(obj, pos) { 
    if(obj.createTextRange) { 
        /* Create a TextRange, set the internal pointer to
           a specified position and show the cursor at this
           position
        */ 
        var range = obj.createTextRange(); 
        range.move('character', pos); 
        range.select(); 
    } else if(obj.selectionStart) { 
        /* Gecko is a little bit shorter on that. Simply
           focus the element and set the selection to a
           specified position
        */ 
        obj.focus(); 
        obj.setSelectionRange(pos, pos); 
    } 
}";
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(//anotherunrelated script);
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(textBox, textBox.GetType(), "MyScript", setCaretTo, true);
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(textBox, textBox.GetType(), "MyStartupScript", "window.onload = function() {obj = window.document.getElementById('"+textBox.ClientID+"');setCaretTo(obj, obj.getAttribute('value').length);}", true);`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://forums.asp.net/t/1087412.aspx) solved it for me:

```
   string setCursorToEndScript = @"function SetCursorToTextEnd(textControlID)
        {
            var text = document.getElementById(textControlID);
            if (text != null && text.value.length > 0)
            {
                if (text.createTextRange)
                {
                    var FieldRange = text.createTextRange();
                    FieldRange.moveStart('character', text.value.length);
                    FieldRange.collapse();
                    FieldRange.select();
                }
            }
        }
          ";

string setFocusScript = @"$get('" + textBox.ClientID + "').focus();";

            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(textBox, textBox.GetType(), "SetCursorToTextEnd", setCursorToEndScript, true);
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(textBox, textBox.GetType(), "selectAndFocus", setFocusScript, true);

            textBox.Attributes.Add("onfocus", "SetCursorToTextEnd('"+ textBox.ClientID +"');");
```

Comment: Where is th selectandFocus function? Could you please providde me with that?

Answer (score 1):

Using the `setCaretTo` function from the link you provide I added the following js:

```
 window.onload = function() {
   obj = window.document.getElementById('myTextBox');
   setCaretTo(obj, obj.getAttribute('value').length);
 }
```

This will set it to the last character.

Comment: Still haven't got it to work. Updated the original post with more information.